# Firefox on an Android tablet

Tags: 7.0-nougat, firefox-for-android

I have just bought an Android 7 TABLET for convenient browsing and reading research (3-4 hours to kill once a week and more, free WiFi available) and for stand-alone navigation (GPS capable).
No SIM slot, no Google account. Tablet has WiFi, USB-2 OTG, micro-SD slot and I've got a spare U1 32Gb card. 
I want to install Firefox so I can quickly synchronise bookmarks with my laptop (Linux Mint 18.3LTS).
Can this be done via a conventional download to either tablet or laptop (whichever is simplest)?

Comment: If the table has Google Play, you can download the Firefox app from the Play store.

Answer (score 1):

On Mozilla's official [wiki page for the Android platform](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android) they have a direct link to [download the apk](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=fennec-latest&os=android&lang=multi) that you can install to your device manually without access to the Play Store through a Google account.